# Parsing data from a collectionview Cell to a new viewController using a button in the CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView that I am populating using an array I created in a class. The collectionView works but the problem is when I want to segue to another viewController using a button in the collectionViewCell as well as parsing specific data from that cell to the viewController.

An example of what I am trying to do is if I press the button in the cell for the question image I want to segue to the next viewController and I want that viewController's image to be the question image, and maybe i the future add some other data corresponding to it.

I have looked at the other answers on this site and other sites, which got me this far, but there is nothing that I can find to fix this problem for a collectionView. I know that it is similar to a tableView, but when I try and change it based on a tableView, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

This is the image of what the first and second views look like

[image: This is the opening View and where the collectionview and cell is]

[image: This is the view I want to parse the data to]

This is the class i created:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Information {

var image = ""
var button = ""
var infoOne = ""
var infoTwo = ""
var price = ""

init(image: String, button: String, infoOne: String, infoTwo: String, price: String) {
    self.image = image
    self.button = button
    self.infoOne = infoOne
    self.infoTwo = infoTwo
    self.price = price
}

//MARK: Carousel Data

static func createData() -> [Information] {
    return [
        Information(image:  "question", button: "Buy One", infoOne: "First Data", infoTwo: "Second Data", price: "10"),
        Information(image: "exclamation", button: "Buy Two", infoOne: "First Data", infoTwo: "Second Data", price: "20"),
        Information(image: "period", button: "Buy Three", infoOne: "First Data", infoTwo: "Second Data", price: "30"),
        Information(image: "all", button: "Buy Four", infoOne: "First Data", infoTwo: "Second Data", price: "40")
    ]
   }
}
```

This array works just fine when it populates the collectionViewCell.

This is the collectionViewCell

```
import UIKit

class InfoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var infomation: Information! {
    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
}

var addBtnAction : (()-> ())?

@IBOutlet weak var infoImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var infoLblOne: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var infoLblTwo: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var priceLbl: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var buyBtn: UIButton!

fileprivate func updateUI() {
    infoImage.image! = UIImage(named: infomation.image)!
    infoLblOne.text = infomation.infoOne
    infoLblTwo.text = infomation.infoTwo
    priceLbl.text = infomation.price
    buyBtn.setTitle(infomation.button, for: .normal)
}

@IBAction func buyBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("INFORMATION: \(infomation.image)")
    addBtnAction?()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    self.clipsToBounds = true
  }
}
```

this is the viewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let collectionViewCellId: String = "carouselCollectionCell"
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

fileprivate var information = Information.createData()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
}

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return information.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "infoCell", for: indexPath) as! InfoCollectionViewCell
    cell.addBtnAction = {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainSegue", sender: self)
    }
    cell.infomation = self.information[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mainSegue" {
        let nxtVC = segue.destination as? DetailViewController
        let cell = sender as! InfoCollectionViewCell
        let myIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        nxtVC?.infomation = information[(myIndexPath?.item)!]
    }
}
}
```

So when I run the app everything is fine until I press the button to segue and parse data. The app crashes and this is what it is saying is the cause:
[image]

This is what is in the output console:

Could not cast value of type 'carousel.ViewController' (0x107992178) to 'carousel.InfoCollectionViewCell' (0x107991f98).
2018-09-28 21:22:52.116698-0400 carousel[1573:38999] Could not cast value of type 'carousel.ViewController' (0x107992178) to 'carousel.InfoCollectionViewCell' (0x107991f98).
(lldb)

I would prefer to keep the button if at all possible, but if it is not possible I will change that. I am not sure what it is that I am doing wrong. If there is anything else that I can help with please let me know. Thank you very much.

EDIT:

It seems that I forgot to include one of the important views, the one for the other viewController that is segued to.

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

this is the view that i segue to:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var infoImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var dataTxtView: UITextView!

var testingImage: UIImage = UIImage()

var infomation: Information! {
    didSet {
        updateUI()

    }
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

fileprivate func updateUI() {


    let images = UIImage(named: infomation.image)
    infoImage.image = images

    print("Image: \(infomation.image)")

    }
}
```

In the updateUI function I tried to make the infoImage the same as infomation.image but it crashes and states:

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This doesn't make much sense to me because I tried to print what the string of infomation.image is, and it worked, but the moment I try and put it as an image it seems to crash. 
Thank you again

EDIT2:

I figured out what I was doing wrong. It seems that I was always trying to use an optional string. How i fixed it is that I changed the class I made and instead of a string and turn that into an image it is already an image. I also tried to create an if let statement to remove the optional.

This is what the prepareForSegue looks like in the main ViewController

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mainSegue" {
        let nxtVC = segue.destination as? DetailViewController

        let cell = sender as? InfoCollectionViewCell
        let myIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell!)

        if let indexPath = myIndexPath {

            nxtVC?.infomation = information[indexPath.row]

        }

    }
}
```

this is what the viewDidLoad looks like:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("***********TESTINGIMAGE: \(infomation.image!)***********")

    infoImage.image = infomation.image!

}
```

I know that I am unwrapping the image with an ! but i don't know how to remove the optional otherwise. 
Thank you for the Help.

Comment: don't use force unwrap `as!` . use `if let` or `guard let `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assuming that the `sender` in `prepare` is an instance of the cell but your call to `performSegue` is passing `self` as the sender. But `self` in that case is the view controller, not the cell.

The solution is to pass the cell instead of `self`.

```
cell.addBtnAction = {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainSegue", sender: cell)
}
```

Comment: Hello, this worked, but it still crashed because it says: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I edited above to show where it is happening. If you can see what is wrong it would be greatly appreciated.